# How do we know that all the Solr nodes in a SolrCloud cluster are in sync?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have a `SolrCloud` setup with `2 Solr nodes` and `3 ZooKeeper nodes`. shards # 1 and `replicationFactor` # 2.

How can I know that both the Solr nodes (leaders/replicas) are in sync and all the index data is replicated successfully?

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SolrCloud API calls are completely consistent in that when the response comes back, it has done so after ALL relevant replicas have confirmed an update received and added to the transaction log (otherwise you'll get an error).

- This is worth reading about [Transaction logs](https://lucidworks.com/2013/08/23/understanding-transaction-logs-softcommit-and-commit-in-sorlcloud/) in particular

> The indexing flow in SolrCloud is as follows:
>
> Incoming documents are received by a node and forwarded to the proper
> leader.
>
> From the leader they’re sent to all replicas for the relevant
> shard.
>
> The replicas respond to their leader.
>
> The leader responds to the originating node.
>
> After all the leaders have responded, the originating node replies to the client. At this point, all documents have been flushed to the tlog for all the nodes in the cluster!

- This is also worth reading as Solr node recovery can impact consistency: [Solr
  consistency and recovery internals](https://www.slideshare.net/cloudera/solr-consistency-and-recovery-internals)

Comment: Thanks Kelly! How can I confirm/verify that index data is replicated to other solr nodes in the SolrCloud?

Comment: You would have received an API error otherwise. Also if you look at the SolrCloud admin console and inspect the shards/replicas - if they're all green it means they're good. Again Solr's API requires that consistency so if the consistency fails you'll get an ERROR on the API call